# Concatenation String - MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

With the Razor view engine, I just want to convert a path like this:

```
src="<%=MyImageServer %>image1.jpg"
```

into

```
src="@MyImageServer[PROBLEM_HERE]image1.jpg"
```

You see the problem... Any Suggestion?

**Note:** MyImageServer is a variable with a path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap in parentheses:

```
src="@(MyImageServer)image1.jpg"
```

But you probably want to avoid such tag soup in your views and write a custom HTML helper:

```
@Html.Image("image1.jpg")
```

which will take care of generating the proper image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really work!. Regarding to your suggestion, I prefer keep the markup language... what do you planning to do with HTML Helper? `return "<img src=\""+ MyImageServer +"image1.jpg\" />"` this really will be a code soup. Don't you think? or `return new Image()...` that slow down performance.

Comment: You could use a `TagBuilder` in your custom helper to avoid the tag soup.